# Class attribute on selected <li> on a JSP tag

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, jstl

I have the following JSP tag `side_menu.tag`:

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<div class="wrap">
    <ul class="main_menu"> 
        <li>X</li>
        <li>Y</li>
        <li>Z</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This tag is used in my wrapper tag, aptly named `wrapper.tag`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="STYLE/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <t:main_banner/>
        <t:side_menu/>
        <jsp:doBody/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thing is, one of the `<li>` should have a `class="selected"` which reflects a styling that makes it different than the rest based on the current action, is there a way to make this dynamic? JSTL perhaps? Or am I tagging and compressing it too much? I'm having trouble coming up with a solution for this other than just eliminating the `side_menu.tag` and repeat the same `<ul>` in every .jsp where I need it.

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: Pass a tag attribute to specify which `<li>` should be selected: `<t:side_menu selected="Z"/>`

Comment: Not really that familiar with jsp in general, just started today, would it be too much to ask for an example?